# How to verify a user's email address on iOS with Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm stuck with email verification with firebase. I've looked around for guidance but no help. After the user verifies his email, my code still prints out the user has not been verified. I'm still trying to get used to the syntax of firebase. Here is my code:

```
if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser!.emailVerified == true{
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email.text!, password: passsword.text!, completion: {
        user, error in

        if error != nil{
            print("Email/password is wrong or user does not exist")
        }else{
            print("Successful login.")
        }
    })
}else{
    print("Please verify your email.")
}
```

here is my code for the sign up section:

```
    let eduEmail = email.text
    let endInEdu = eduEmail?.hasSuffix("my.utsa.edu")

    if endInEdu == true {

        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email.text!, password: passsword.text!, completion: {
            user, error in

            if error != nil{
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "User exists.", message: "Please use another email or sign in.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                print("Email has been used, try a different one")
                }else{

 FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser!.sendEmailVerificationWithCompletion({ (error) in
                      })


                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Account Created", message: "Please verify your email by confirming the sent link.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)








                print("This is a college email and user is created")




            }


        })


    }else{
        print("This is not a my.utsa.edu email")
        }
```

Comment: Hey Jesus! Welcome to stackoverflow. I stronggly recommend you to set a more descriptive question title.

Comment: Are you calling sendEmailVerification on the currentUser and then clicking the email verification link that is emailed?

Comment: Yes I am. It's in my signup view controller file. Once you sign up, it automatically sends the email when it creates the account

Comment: I edited the code in.

Answer (score 13):

You checked if the user email was verified even before signing them in.

This is what worked for me.

```
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(txtUsername.text!, password: txtPassword.text!) {
        (user, error) in
        if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
            if !user.emailVerified{
                let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Sorry. Your email address has not yet been verified. Do you want us to send another verification email to \(self.txtUsername.text).", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                let alertActionOkay = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .Default) {
                    (_) in
                        user.sendEmailVerificationWithCompletion(nil)
                }
                let alertActionCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: nil)

                alertVC.addAction(alertActionOkay)
                alertVC.addAction(alertActionCancel)
                self.presentViewController(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                print ("Email verified. Signing in...")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the coalescing operator after `FIRAuth.auth()` which means the following method call will return `nil` when `FIRAuth.auth()` was nil. If this is the case, your comparison with `true` will fail, since `nil` is not `true`.

I suggest you to refactor your code like this for easier debugging:

```
guard let auth = FIRAuth.auth(), user = auth.currentUser else {
    print("No auth / user")
}

guard user.emailVerified else {
    print("Email not verified")
    return
}

guard let email = email.text, password = passsword.text else {
    print("No email or password")
    return
}

auth.signInWithEmail(email, password: password) { user, error in
    if let error = error {
        print("Email/password is wrong or user does not exist, error: \(error)")
    } else {
        print("Successful login.")
    }
}
```

You should find your error easier like this.

Comment: I still get the same "Email is not verified" even after verifying the email.

Comment: @jesusnieto5413 Well then something went wrong on the firebase side, can't help you more than that

Comment: @jesusnieto5413 did you find the solution? , I have the same problem. I do verification but still isEmailVerified returns False.