# Why my createUser Method Trigger addStateDidChangeListener Method in appDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

In app delegate, I write codes to decide whether the user will go straight to Main Tab Bar if the user has already sign in, otherwise the user will be sent to Welcome Screen VC when the app is launched.

here is the code in my App Delegate.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        checkUserLogin()


        // to track the user default info.plist location in the device (simulator) for checking purpose.
        print("The Location of info.plist of User Default: \(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).last! as String)")


        return true
    }

}




    extension AppDelegate {

        // MARK: - HELPER METHODS

        func checkUserLogin() {
            // to check whether the user has already logged in or not


            SVProgressHUD.show()
            Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in

                if user == nil {
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    self.goToWelcomeVC()
                } else {
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    self.goToMainTabBar()
                }

                // if user is not nil then automatically go to maintab bar (initialVC is indeed main tab bar controller)
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            }
        }



        func goToMainTabBar () {
             print("XXXXXXXX")
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let mainTabBar = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainTabBar")
            window?.rootViewController = mainTabBar

        }

        func goToWelcomeVC () {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Welcome", bundle: nil)
            let login = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WelcomeVC")
            window?.rootViewController = login

        }


    }
```

I am trying to create registerVC, after the user fill the text field, and press the register button I try to create user by using Firebase Authentication, the code will be triggered when the user press sign up button in registerVC

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
  // ...
}
```

when `Auth.auth().createUser()` is triggered, it is automatically triggered `Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener()` method in my app delegate, so it makes my app automatically go to Main Tab Bar, at this point I want my app still in RegistrationVC, since the user have to verified their email first and then login to go to Main Tab Bar.

how to prevent the user to go to MainTab Bar when the `Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)` is triggered? but I also want to keep the functionality the user will go straight to Main Tab Bar if the user has already sign in, otherwise the user will be sent to Welcome Screen VC when the app is launched. ?

Comment: When you create a user that user is automaticly signed in so i think you will have to change your logic a bit if you only want to go to next screen after the email has been verified. You could check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38406024/4916627)

Answer (score 1):

You might resolved your problem by now, but this answer is for record.
I faced the same problem, and I solved it like this:

1 - Replace the inside of `if user == nil {` with:

```
let registeration = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "registering")
if(!registeration) {
     SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
     self.goToWelcomeVC()
}
```

2 - Above `Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in` line, add:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "registering")
```

3 - In your mainTabBar VC, inside `viewDidLoad` func, add this:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "registering")
```